# unable to open activity on notification click

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to open different classes depending upon notification content which i have received. I am able to open MainActivity class on notification click but not OpenActivityOne. Don't know the reason why.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Call")){
        System.out.println("Inside iffffffffffffffffffffff");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, OpenActivityOne.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }else{

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

OpenActivityOne.java

```
 public class OpenActivityOne extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open OpenActivityOne",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Probably two reasons: 1. `OpenActivityOne` is not added in `AndroidManifest.xml` and 2. `msg ` is not equals to `Call`, for second case try it using `String.contains`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it is declared inside AndroidManifest otherwise would have given error much before. and it is entering inside if checked using log--System.out.println(inside ifff);

Comment: ok then add log in `onCreate ` of `OpenActivityOne ` and check it's `OpenActivityOne ` is executing or not

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Adding a flag in `Activity` in `AndroidManifiest.xml`

```
android:exported="true"
```

Like

```
<activity
        android:name="com.your.OpenActivityOne"
        android:exported="true" >
.
.
</activity>
```